# How to exclude numbers from Lucene Indexing?

Tags: java, lucene

I am working on an information retrieval application, using Lucene 5.3.1 (latest as of now), I managed to index the terms from a text file and then search within it. The text file happens to contain chapter numbers like `2.1`, `3.4.2` and so on and so forth.

The problem is that I don't need these numbers indexed, as I have no need to search for them, and I haven't been able to find out how to exclude certain terms from the tokenizing, I know the `Analyzer` uses the StopWords set to exclude several terms, but it doesn't do anything with numbers as far as I know.

Comment: There's no single `Analyzer` - you can write your own, or just write a `TokenFilter` that gets rid of what you don't want indexed.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer I can come up with – *remove numbers from text before indexing*. You can use regular expressions for that. This solution has one side effect – `PositionIncrementAttribute` will be calculated without those numbers, as they do not appear in text. This can broke some of your `PhraseQuery`'ies.

Another option, as were already mentioned – write custom `TokenFilter` to strip numbers out. But you should remember:

- to tune `Analyzer` to not explode terms on dots. Otherwise `2.1` will be two terms instead of one. This again can cause problems with `PhraseQuery`;
- correctly change value of `PositionIncrementAttribute` (increment it) while removing terms from `TokenStream`.